# What do we call it when someone injures himself?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do we call it when someone **injures himself** on purpose because of a mental problem? For example, they cut their own flesh or something.

Comment: More information is needed. The question is ambiguous.

Comment: If you are asking for the formal term, it might vary by country.  https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-scarred-soul/201002/non-suicidal-self-injury-new-diagnosis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *generic* terminology is [**self-harm**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-harm):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : the act of purposely hurting oneself (as by cutting or burning the skin) as an emotional coping mechanism
>
> • Although most cutters are young women who have been emotionally, sexually, or physically abused as children, [Marilee] Strong's research shows that this specific type of *self-harm* also appears in other groups. —Maria Simson et al.

As mentioned in a comment, and by Merriam-Webster, this can also be known as *self-injury* or *self-mutilation*.

Comment: Thank you. So what's the difference between this one and "self-laceration"? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Laceration is a specific type of harm. (As would be burning or other particular activities.)  I think it would be more common to refer to harm in general. "They have a tendency to self-harm." "Oh, that's too bad." "What form does it take?" "Cutting" You would probably only say *self-laceration* if you wanted to specify the form of the harm right away.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to any type of injury, then it can be called **self-injury**. If you're referring specifically to people who "cut their own flesh", then that's called **cutting**. Both of these words have verb forms.

This short passage from [TeensHealth](https://kidshealth.org/en/teens/cutting.html) shows both the noun and verb forms of these words in action (emphasis added):

> Injuring yourself on purpose by making scratches or cuts on your body with a sharp object — enough to break the skin and make it bleed — is called **cutting**. Cutting is a type of **self-injury**, or SI. People who **cut** often start cutting in their young teens. Some continue to cut into adulthood.
>
> People may **cut themselves** on their wrists, arms, legs, or bellies. Some people **self-injure** by burning their skin with the end of a cigarette or lighted match.

Answer (score 0):

We can use **self-laceration** which [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-laceration):

> the act or action of cutting or tearing one's own flesh

Comment: self-laceration is a psychological condition. Is this what you are looking for? Self-injury is also used. However, I can injure myself in any number of ways, not on purpose. Do you mean on purpose or not?

Comment: Yes, I mean on purpose.

Comment: Ok, so you answered your own question. Sometimes self-injury is also used.

Comment: I've never heard this term used before. I mean, anyone would understand it, but they would be confused about why you didn't just say **cutting** (common and meaning the same thing) or self-harm (also common, but less specific). I would recommend against using this term in AmE environments. Can't speak for BrE though